# C++ enum redefenition and C++0x

Tags: c++, enums, c++11

If I want to exclude problems with enums and type redefinition in C++ I can use the code:

```
struct VertexType
{
    enum
    {
        Vector2 = 1,
        Vertor3 = 2,
        Vector4 = 3,
    };
};

struct Vector2 { ... };
struct Vector3 { ... };
struct Vector3 { ... };
```

Is there a way to remove the wrapper above enum. I looked at C++0x but didn't find addiditional inforamtion about solving this problem.

Comment: I might be slow, but could someone explain what the problem is with the current code exactly ? Wouldn't a namespace solve this ?

Comment: In C# I could just define an enum without any wrapper because enum elemetns can be accessed only like EnumName.EnumElement, in C++ EnumElement belongs to a global scope and can be accessed without EnumName::.

Comment: I.e. in C#, `EnumName` _is_ the wrapper (namespace).

Comment: `namespace` is the most immediate solution. But C++ templates are the usual way of enumerating over (or even generating) types. Consider `template< int N > struct vector { enum { dimensions = N }; ... };`. This allows simple translation between the numbers and the types. You can implement a general case and/or specific classes as you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `namespace`?

```
namespace VertexType
{
    enum V
    {
        Vector2 = 1,
        Vertor3 = 2,
        Vector4 = 3,
    };
}

struct Vector2 { ... };
struct Vector3 { ... };
struct Vector4 { ... };
```

Comment: Namespace looks better than struct. But don't you know does C++0x add the local scope for enum elements?

Comment: Yep, namespace is the right way to limit the scope of enumerators, I prefer doing it this way. As a bonus you get argument-dependent name lookup.

Comment: And I can't use a namespace for wrapping an enum if I want to create an enum type field;

Comment: @MaxFX: Of course you can. The enum type is named `VertexType::V`

Answer (score 5):

Since you are talking about C++0x, just use the new `enum class` syntax:

```
enum class VertexType {
   Vector1 = 1,
   Vector2 = 2,
   Vector4 = 3
};
```

The enumerator values will only be accessible through the `VertexType` type as in `VertexType::Vector1`.

Some quotes from the standard:

> §7.2/2 [...] The enum-keys enum class and enum struct are semantically equivalent; an enumeration type declared with one of these is a scoped enumeration, and its enumerators are scoped enumerators. [...]
>
> §7.2/10 [...] Each scoped enumerator is declared in the scope of the enumeration.[...]

```
// example in §7.2/10
enum class altitude { high=’h’, low=’l’ };
void h() {
  altitude a;        // OK
  a = high;          // error: high not in scope
  a = altitude::low; // OK
}
```

Comment: +1. Nice feature I knew nothing about. Has this anything to do with the Java enums (which are classes and can have methods) ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears vector3 is already being used. You can do what your trying to do, however, vector3 cannot be used.

```
enum //VertexType
{
    Vector2 = 1,
    //Vector3 = 2,
    Vector4 = 3,
};

struct Vector2 { ... };
//struct Vector3 {  };
struct Vector3 { ... };
```

This works for me, no errors at all.

This is a link i found.
http://www.kixor.net/dev/vector3/